# Video created from JPEG images in Spring Boot using FFmpegBuilder is extremely resource demanding

Tags: spring-boot, ffmpeg

I have created small JAVA app which transforms a set of input JPEG images into video

For that purpose i use 
***net.bramp.ffmpeg.builder.FFmpegBuilder***

```
    FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
                .addInput(imagesSourceFolder)

                .addOutput(videoOutputPath)             
                .setFormat("mp4")
                .setVideoCodec("libx264")
                .setVideoResolution(1280, 720)
                .disableSubtitle() 
                .disableAudio()
                .setVideoFrameRate(FFmpeg.FPS_24)

                .done();
```

Everything works just fine

But the problem is that video created like this is very resource demanding
For instance, when i play it in VLC it slows my whole system
When i try to stream that video and open it in Browser, 
everything becomes unresponsive,
except for video that keeps running

Any idea why videos created in this way are so resource demanding?

Comment: Do all 24 fps, 1280x720, H.264 videos act like that for you, or only the ones you created?

Comment: Thanks for comment didnt think in that direction even for a moment until you left comment

Comment: For this exercise my sys admin created  virtual machine for me, 16cores 32GB of ram, SSD, but no GPU, so this was a problem